# Can we initialize a pointer with a variable qualified as constant and having value 0 in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr, null-pointer

According to the book C++ Primer, we can assign a variable qualified as const and having value 0 to a pointer. Here's the relevant line from the book.

> It is okay to assign the literal 0 or a const whose value is known to be 0 at compile time:

and then the following code snippet is provided.

```
int ival;
int zero = 0;
const int c_ival = 0;
int *pi = ival;        // error
pi = zero;             // error
pi = c_ival            // ok: c_ival is a const with compile-time value of 0
```

However, when I run a similar code, an error is thrown.

```
int main()
{
    const int c_ival = 0;
    int *pi = c_ival;            
}
```

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What compiler, and compiler flags are you using exactly?

Comment: This will compile in C++98, but not in C++11+. In modern C++, prefer the use of [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your version of the C++ Primer (and indirectly the standard revision it's targeting), this may just be a case of outdated information.

You see, there was a change of definition between C++03 and C++11. In the past, it said:

> **[conv.ptr]**
>
> 1 A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19)
> rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

But an outstanding defect report ([CWG 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903)) was applied retroactively to C++11 and changed the wording to

> **[conv.ptr]**
>
> 1 A null pointer constant is an integer literal (5.13.2 [lex.icon])
> with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.

So since C++11 `c_ival` no longer qualifies. It's not a *literal* 0, despite still being a constant expression with value 0.

Comment: Might even be worth mentioning that this disqualifies expressions like `1-1`.

Comment: @cigien - Or something like `#define FALSE ('-'-'-')` too ;)

Answer (score 0):

`c_ival` is of type `int`. `pi` is of type `int*`. You can't implicitly convert `int` to `int*` so you have to use a type cast:

```cpp
int *pi = (int*) c_ival; // C-style cast
// --or--
int *pi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(c_ival); // C++ style cast
```

Both of these methods work but are pretty gross. Just assign `nullptr` to pointers that don't point to anything and stay away from zeros.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we initialize a pointer with a variable qualified as constant and having value 0 in C++?

We used to. We no longer can since C++11.

> What am I doing wrong?

You're reading an obsolete edition of the book.